# update geolocation every * seconds but not when lat/long doesnt change

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Ok so I have something that grabs the users geolocation, as this user could be moving it is setup to a timed setTimeout to re-run the geolocation function every 3 secs which if they're moving would show their progress, however I want it that if they haven't moved, e.g their latitude and longitude are the same then don't update, as there is no reason too.

my thinking is along the following:

```
function startGeolocation() {
  var options;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFail, options);
}

//get various coordinates
function geoSuccess(position) {
  var gpsPosition = position;
  var coordinates = gpsPosition.coords;

//if its the first run through and myLat is empty, then continue as normal.
  if (!myLat){
  myLat = coordinates.latitude;
  myLong = coordinates.longitude;

//if its the second run through and the myLat is the same as it was before, do nothing.
    }else if ((myLat == myLatSame) && (myLong == myLongSame)){ 
    }

//else if they are different, e.g user has moved, then update.
else{
    myLat = coordinates.latitude;
    myLong = coordinates.longitude;
    setTimeout(geoSuccess, 3000);
}
myLatSame = myLat;
myLongSame = myLong;
}
```

it doesn't seem to work, and the page stops loading the map totally.

however if i go back to very basic code,

```
function startGeolocation() {
 var options;
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFail, options);
 setTimeout(startGeolocation, 3000);
}

function geoSuccess(position) {
  var gpsPosition = position;
  var coordinates = gpsPosition.coords;
  myLat = coordinates.latitude;
  myLong = coordinates.longitude;
```

this works fine and updates every 3 seconds.

i've come back from a long hiatus on coding javascript so my syntax and methodology is a little rusty.
thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I have added a few alerts to the code and on first run through the following happens:
its first run through so alert(before if) = undefined for myLat and myLong.
!myLat is true as it holds nothing so myLat and myLong get filled with coords and alerted in the alert(in if), the following alert(myLatSame + myLongSame) come back as "NaN"

the else if is not triggered as the are not the same,
however the else alert(else) statement is ALSO not triggered and is not seen.

```
//get various coordinates
function geoSuccess(position) {
  var gpsPosition = position;
  var coordinates = gpsPosition.coords;
alert("before if \n" + myLat + "\n" + myLong);
//if its the first run through and myLat is empty, then continue as normal.
  if (!myLat){
  myLat = coordinates.latitude;
  myLong = coordinates.longitude;
alert("in if \n" + myLat + "\n" + myLong);
alert(myLatSame + myLongSame);

//if its the second run through and the myLat is the same as it was before, do nothing.
    }else if ((myLat == myLatSame) && (myLong == myLongSame)){ 
    alert("in else if \n" + myLat + "\n" + myLong);
    }

//else if they are different, e.g user has moved, then update.
{
    myLat = coordinates.latitude;
    myLong = coordinates.longitude;
        alert("else \n" + myLat + "\n" + myLong);
    setTimeout(geoSuccess, 3000);   
}

myLatSame = myLat;
myLongSame = myLong;
}
```

Comment: And? What's the problem? Does it work? Are there errors? Where is the question?

Comment: sorry, got sidetracked elsewhere. the code doesn't work and the map now doesn't load at all.

Comment: nope none. ive just added in some alert()s at various intervals in the statements, and none are being fired.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend exploring the use of `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` over `getCurrentPosition()`

watchPosition will fire if there is a change to user. But you can also tell the function to wait before checking using the options.

Example use:

```
tracker = navigator.geolocation;

watchId = tracker.watchPosition(savePosition,  displayError, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 20000 });
```

maxiumAge is the time between readings in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I think the error might be for the fact that your variables

```
myLatSame = myLat;
myLongSame = myLong;
```

The scope may be limited to the function itself and not on a global scope. Is the values reatined? Can you alert the values?
Also check if the console is showing any errors, and check you have closed all your brackets. From you current code sample you attached, it's missing a closing brace in the end.

EDIT: You also need to add the Timeout function to your first IF.

```
     if (!myLat){
  myLat = coordinates.latitude;
  myLong = coordinates.longitude;
alert("in if \n" + myLat + "\n" + myLong);
alert(myLatSame + myLongSame);
setTimeout(geoSuccess, 3000);
//if its the second run through and the myLat is the same as it was before, do nothing.
    }else if
```

Comment: i declared the variables outside the startGeolocation() function and the various alerts I've added in are alerting, will update main question to show progress.